# Error when trying to get Value from a Dataframe

Tags: python

I am trying to get the value from a cell in dataframe. The attached is my code:

```py
Ftr=f['Word'].iloc[k]
# print((Ftr))
if Ftr in list1:
    X=f['Token'].iloc[k]
```

But when i am executing it, for a couple of strings I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/shells/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'miscforsale'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-147-a82083f97449>", line 1, in <module>
    PA_posterior['miscforsale'][0]

  File "/Users/shells/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "/Users/shells/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'miscforsale'
```

Can anyone please help me solve this?

Comment: it's hard to help you without seeing what your data looks like, and what your variables are (such as `f` and `List1` and `k`). Also, in the error, it says there is an error with this statement:`PA_posterior['miscforsale'][0]`, but it doesn't appear in your code. Did you show everything?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, don't have enough reputation to comment.

Your DataFrame most likely does not contain a column with the name "miscforsale".

Remember that every time you get a "KeyError" you should look at your code accessing the columns of the DataFrame and see if the names actually match.

I can't give you much help because you have not stated your DataFrame structure.